# For a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to\mathbb{R}^{+}$ does $(f(x)-f(y)) (f(\frac{x+y}{2}) - f(\sqrt{xy}))=0$ imply that $f$ is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is a continuous function such that for all positive real numbers $x,y$ the following is true :
$$(f(x)-f(y)) \left ( f \left ( \frac{x+y}{2} \right ) - f ( \sqrt{xy} ) \right )=0.$$
Is it true that the only solution to this is the constant function ?

Comment: Actually there are some narrow gaps which if avoided makes the problem very simple.

Comment: By "makes the problem very simple", do you mean to say that you have a solution and are asking this as a riddle?  Because if so, it should be made clear that MathOverflow is for asking questions which you *do not* know how to answer (at the time when you are asking).  Maybe you should clarify how you came across this problem.

Comment: No I actually couldn't edit that comment . Ok but you read "makes the problem simple" but did not see why I wrote "there are some narrow gaps" anyways I meant that if we had a better function f (instead of just being a continuous one) which would have shown the property that if f took two different values at some places (say f(a) $\ne$ f(b) and $a<b$ ) then f would behave injective over some subinterval of $(a,b)$ .                                           And this is not a fake exercise.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample for a discontinuous function?

Comment: Yes you may think of the function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ then see that the condition is not valid "for all" positive reals x,y. Hence a contradiction !!

Comment: Also an example which shows why the "injective over some subinterval" argument won't work is the Weierstrass function .

Comment: I added a solution based on the "injective over some subinterval" argument.

Comment: For a discontinuous example take $f$ to be the characteristic function of the transcendental numbers. If $x$ and $y$ are both algebraic or both transcendental then the first factor, $f(x)-f(y)$, vanishes. If one is algebraic and the other transcendental then $(x+y)/2$ and $\sqrt{xy}$ are both transcendental and the second factor vanishes. (Here the fact that $x$ and $y$ are not allowed to be zero is important!)

Comment: Nice example! Note that for the theorem to hold f need not be continuous. For example, you can replace it by $g\circ f$, where $g $ is any permutation of the reals. In fact, my proof relies only on the fact that the inverse image of any number is a closed set. My question is: Is any function with that property a composition of a continuous function and a permutation?

Comment: Every constant function is continuous. So how can you ensure $f$ is constant claiming that $f$ is not continuous ? So, I don't see any point in claiming existence of discontinuous functions that obey this (means obeys the truth of the given and also they are constant functions). However it may be sensible to see if a proof needs something weaker than continuity, but remember that continuity will eventually be implied. Also initially the main interest was to investigate this property of "continuous" functions.

Comment: You're right, I was not precise enough. I'm looking for a generalization of the theorem. Let me try to state one. Let "~" be an equivalence relation on the (positive) reals. Suppose 1) "~" has closed classes; 2) for all x < y, either x~y or there exists x <z < (x+y)/2 such that z~(x+y)/2. Then, "~" is trivial (namely, any two reals are equivalent).

Comment: Just for the record, this is Problem 4 in Year 2015 of the notoriously difficult Hungarian mathematics competition for undergraduates (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1224690p6149915).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes.  If $f$ were not constant, then (since ${\bf R}^+$ is connected) it could not be locally constant, thus there exists $x_0 \in {\bf R}^+$ such that $f$ is not constant in any neighbourhood of $x_0$.  By rescaling (replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x_0 x)$) we may assume without loss of generality that $x_0=1$.

For any $y \in {\bf R}^+$, there thus exists $x$ arbitrarily close to $1$ for which $f(x) \neq f(y)$, hence $f((x+y)/2) = f(\sqrt{xy})$.  By continuity, this implies that $f((1+y)/2) = f(\sqrt{y})$ for all $y \in {\bf R}^+$.  Making the substitution $z := (1+y)/2$, we conclude that $f(z) = f(g(z))$ for all $z > 1/2$, where $g(z) := \sqrt{2z-1}$. The function $g$ attracts $[1, \infty)$ to the fixed point $z=1$, so on iteration and by using the continuity of $f$ we conclude that $f(z)=f(1)$ for all $z >1$. Similarly, $h = g^{-1}$ defined by $h(z) = (z^2 + 1)/2$ attracts $(0, 1]$ to the fixed point $z = 1$, so by the same argument $f(z) = f(1)$ for $z < 1$, making $f$ constant on all of $\bf R^+$.

Comment: Slick, very slick.

Comment: This proof is strong. Also shows the pair $(AM,GM)$ can be replaced by some other terms (some relaxations maybe possible) and yet the result will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make sense of Igor's argument. Assume further that $f$ is defined on 0 and relaxt the continuity assumption by only assuming that the set $A=\{x>0:f (x)\neq f (0)\}$ is open.

It is shown that $A=\emptyset  $ by showing that

1. $A $ is dense in $A+\mathbb R^+$, and
2. $A\cap 2A=\emptyset $.

**Proof.** (1) Let $(a,b) $ be a connected component of  $A $. For every $0 <r <b-a  $, $b+r\in A $ since the arithmetic average of $b\pm r $ is not in $A $ whereas the geometric is. It follows that the next connected component contains $(b,2b-a) $ and, by applying the same argument on the next component, the elements of $[a,\infty )\setminus A $ are at least $b-a $ apart from one another.

(2) Let $a\in A $. $a $ is the arithmetic average of 0 and $2a $ and 0 is their geometric.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution (to the original question).

Define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R^+$ by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$. 
Since $f$ is continuous,

1. every equivalence class is closed.

Let $0<x<y$. Since $y=\frac {x +(2y-x)}{2}$, either $x\sim 2y-x$ or there exists $z\in (x,y)$ such that $z\sim y$. Therefore,

2. for every $x<y$, if [$\forall z\in(x,y)$ $z\not\sim y$] then $x\sim 2y-x$.

It suffices to prove the following proposition.

> **Proposition 1.** Every equivalence relation on $\mathbb R^+$ that satisfies (1) and (2) is trivial (i.e., has one equivalence class).

**Proof.**
Suppose there were a non-trivial equivalence relation "$\sim$" satisfying (1) and (2).

*Step 1. Every equivalence class is unbounded and its interior is either unbounded or empty.*

Suppose $\langle x\rangle$ were an equivalence class which is either bounded or has a non-empty bounded interior. There exits $\epsilon\geq 0$ such that $\langle x\rangle$ contains an interval of length $\epsilon$, and there exists $x'=\max\{x'': [x'',x''+\epsilon]\subset \langle x\rangle\}$. Take some $y \in (x',\infty)\setminus \langle x\rangle$, and let $y'=\min (
\langle  y\rangle\cap[x',\infty))$. By (2), $[x',x'+\epsilon]'\sim 2y'-[x',x'+\epsilon]$ contradicting the maximality of $x'$.

*Step 2. Every equivalence class is an arithmetic sequence.*

Let $\langle x\rangle$ be an equivalence class. If $x_0=\inf \langle x \langle >0$, then by (2) the elements of $(x_0,2x_0)$ are not in $\langle x\rangle$. Since $\langle x\rangle$ is unbounded and closed, there is a minimal $r_x\geq x_0$ such that $x_0+r_x\in\langle x\rangle$. By (2), the elements of $(x_0,x_0+r_x)$ are not in $\langle x\rangle$ and $x_0+r_x$ is in $\langle x\rangle$. Applying the same argument inductively on all intervals $[x_0+nr_x,x_0+(n+1)r_x]$, we get $\langle x\rangle=\mathbb R^+\cap (x+r_x\mathbb Z)$.

Suppose $\inf \langle x \rangle = 0$ then, the compliment of $\langle x \rangle$ contains an interval $(a,b)$ such that $a,b\in \langle x \rangle$ and starting from that interval $\langle x \rangle$ is an arithmetic sequence with period $b-a$. Since this is the case for any such intervals, they must all have the same length; therefore $\inf \mathbb R^+\setminus\langle x\rangle >0$. Since $\langle x\rangle$ has a bounded interior it must have an empty interior (by Claim 1); therefore it does not contain a prefix of $\mathbb R^+$, so $\inf \langle x \rangle >0$.

*Step 3. For every $x$ and  $y$, $r_y \leq r_x$ with strict inequality for some $x,y$. Contradiction!*

Let $x\not\sim y$. There exists $x'\sim x$ such that $\langle y\rangle\cap(x',x'+r_x)\neq\emptyset$. By (2), since $\forall z\in(x',x'+r_x)\ z\not\sim x'+r_x$, $\langle y\rangle\cap(x'+r_x,x'+2r_x)\neq\emptyset$. By induction, $\langle y\rangle\cap(x'+nr_x,x'+(n+1)r_x)\neq\emptyset$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$; therefore $r_y\leq r_x$. Take $x$ and $y=x+\frac 2 3 r_x$. By (2), $y\sim y'=x+\frac 4 3 r_x$. It follows that $r_y\leq |y'-y|<r_x$.

Answer (score -1):

if $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of non-negative real numbers, your condition implies that 
$$(f(x)-f(0)) (f(\frac{x}2)-f(0)) = 0$$ for all positive $x,$ which is pretty convincing (setting $g(x) = f(x) - f(0),$ the function $g$ will be identically $0.$).

**Addendum** Since the map $(x, y) -> (x+y)/2, \sqrt{x y})$ is surjective onto the set $x>y,$ if your function were real analytic and nonconstant, then the set where your condition held would be a subvariety of $R^+ \times R^+,$ so assuming more regularity makes the problem easy, as pointed out in comments.

Comment: No firstly $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of all positive reals (so $0$ is not included in the domain) . Also if $0$ was included in the domain still I think there remains a flaw in your argument which you can easily see because to infer your conclusion of $f(x) \cdot f(x/2)=0$ we would need $f(0)=0$ and then by our condition (of $f(x) \cdot f(x/2)=0$ ) for every $x$ and the continuity we get $f \equiv 0$ as the "only" solution which is not true since any constant function (obviously obeying the positivity of codomain ) fits in. So I ask you to check your solution to find the flaw.

Comment: @adityaguharoy You are right that what I wrote is not quite correct, but almost.

Comment: @adityaguharoy see edit.

Comment: @Igor $f(0)$ is not defined!

Comment: @Igor Rivin   Yes now that is a nice work (really good), and we would have got a clean solution if the domain of f was non-negative reals but unfortunately 0 is not in the domain.

Comment: @DanPetersen If you look at the text it says that IF the domain includes zero THEN the argument works, so the fact that $f(0)$ is not defined (as clarified by the OP) means that the answer is to a slightly different question.

Comment: @IgorRivin I must be missing something. Let $g(x)$ be nonzero on the interval $(0.9,1.1)$ and zero everywhere else. Then $g(x) g(x/2)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes you are correct. So we are not yet done. (In one of the earlier comments I wrote a flaw) .

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Guilty as charged.

Comment: I tried to correct the proof. See answer below.