# Which functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective over some subinterval of $(x,y)$ whenever $x<y$ and $f(x) \ne f(y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Under what conditions on a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can we say that given any real numbers $x,y$ with $x<y$ if $f(x) \ne f(y)$ then there is a sub-interval $S_{(x,y)}$ of $(x,y)$ such that $f$ behaves injective on $S_{(x,y)}$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately continuity is not enough : (The devil here is) the Weierstrass function.

Comment: Differentiablity is of course enough.

Comment: @ClaudioGorodski I think differentiability over the whole domain is necessary (just think about the step functions).

Comment: In general, I think absolute continuity is enough, though it may not be the strongest and the best solution to it. Also it may have some lacks.

Comment: Ok if you (anyone) suspects the source : I say I never read it being true. I actually was thinking about it because I felt that if this was true for certain (though peculiarly) general functions then many things were true for many general categories of functions (one such thing is : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269064/for-a-continuous-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-does-fx-fy ) , however unfortunately it is not so general that it holds with the sufficiency of continuity, but I don't know what to tell about absolute continuity.

Comment: For the step function see that it is (nearly trivial) devil that prevents us from having differentiability 'the-almost' everywhere, though yes I think the total differentiability may do a clean work. Also if anyone has a proof about any claims on differentiable functions / absolutely continuous functions etc . , you can post it here.